# How to expand a string in Ruby based on some condition?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, string

I have a string `a5bc2cdf3`. I want to expand it to `aaaaabcbccdfcdfcdf`.

In the string is `a5`, so the resulting string should contain 5 consecutive "a"s, "bc2" results in "bc" appearing 2 times consecutively, and `cdf` should repeat `3` times.

If input is `a5bc2cdf3`, and output is `aaaaabcbccdfcdfcdf` how can I do this in a Ruby method?

```
def get_character("compressed_string",index)
  expanded_string = calculate_expanded_string(compressed_string)
  required_char = expanded_string(char_at, index_number(for eg 3))
end

def calculate_expanded_string(compressed_string)
  return expanded
end
```

Comment: Please pay attention to using proper grammar. "i" is "I". Stack Overflow is an online reference book, not a discussion list, and grammar, spelling, punctuation and formatting matter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use a regex like

```
.gsub(/([a-zA-Z]+)(\d+)/){$1*$2.to_i}
```

See the [Ruby online demo](https://ideone.com/7yFID6)

The `/([a-zA-Z]+)(\d+)/` will match stubstrings with 1+ letters (`([a-zA-Z]+)`) and 1+ digits (`(\d+)`) and will capture them into 2 groups that are later used inside a block to return the string you need.

Note that instead of `[a-zA-Z]` you might consider using `\p{L}` that can match any letters.

You want to break out of `gsub` once the specified index is reached in the original "compressed" string. It is still possible, see [this Ruby demo](https://ideone.com/OUHPFK):

```
s = 'a5bc2cdf3'                # input string
index = 5                      # break index
result = ""                    # expanded string
s.gsub!(/([a-zA-Z]+)(\d+)/){   # regex replacement
    result << $1*$2.to_i       # add to the resulting string
    break if Regexp.last_match.end(0) >= index  # Break if the current match end index is bigger or equal to index
}
puts result[index]            # Show the result
# => b
```

For brevity, you may replace `Regexp.last_match` with `$~`.

Comment: but here we know  that at what positions the number is present. what if a  string comes dynamically to this method, in that we dont know how many numbers are present, and at what positions the numbers are present?

Comment: Just to clarify: you want to be able to limit the number of expansions? What is the `index` supposed to do?

Comment: in the expanded string "aaaaabcbccdfcdfcdf".(passing the index) . that is "5" then i should get "b" chracter as the index start from zero.

Comment: After you get the result, you can get any char at any index you want. See https://ideone.com/cLLUNG

Comment: for example  in my case the character that iam trying to get is at index "5". so once the string length reaches to "5" then i want to stop this method execution. why because some body may send a big string lets say a string of "500" characters. how can i achieve this? and there is no point to wait till we get last character of the expanded string. because my index is only "5"

Comment: Ok, just to double check: that long string will be a compressed string, but as far as I understand you want to get the index of a char in an already expanded string. Rght? And now, you want to check the length of the expanded string on the go, and once the whole substring changed reaches the index, abort `gsub`?

Comment: some people might send a compressed string of length "500" characters. then as per the logic it computes the expanded string. and in the expanded string i will search character at "5". so the method should not execute further till the end. because the expanded string length reached to  "5".

Answer (score 2):

I would propose to use `scan` to move over the compressed string, using a simple RegEx which detects groups of non-decimal characters followed by their count as decimal `/([^\d]+)(\d+)/`.

```
def get_character(compressed_string, index)
  result = nil

  compressed_string.scan(/([^\d]+)(\d+)/).inject(0) do |total_length, (chars, count)|
    decoded_string = chars * count.to_i
    total_length += decoded_string.length

    if index < total_length
      result = decoded_string[-(total_length - index)]
      break
    else
      total_length
    end
  end

  result
end
```

Knowing the current (total) length, one can break out of the loop if the current expanded string includes the requested index. The string is never decoded entirely.

This code gives the following results

```
get_character("a5bc2cdf3", 5)  # => "b"
get_character("a5bc2cdf3", 10) # => "d"
get_character("a5bc2cdf3", 20) # => nil
```

Comment: Just wanted to add, that this snippet works this way because of the comments on Wiktors answer, e.g. that the code should stop decompressing the input if the index is reached.

Answer (score 0):

Just another way. I prefer Wiktor's method by a long way.

```
def stringy str, index
  lets, nums = str.split(/\d+/), str.split(/[a-z]+/)[1..-1].map(&:to_i)
  ostr = lets.zip(nums).map { |l,n| l*n }.join
  ostr[index]
end

str = 'a5bc2cdf3'
p stringy str, 5 #=> "b"
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd use:

```
str = "a5bc2cdf3"
str.split(/(\d+)/).each_slice(2).map { |s, c| s * c.to_i }.join # => "aaaaabcbccdfcdfcdf"
```

Here's how it breaks down:

```
str.split(/(\d+)/) # => ["a", "5", "bc", "2", "cdf", "3"]
```

This works because `split` will return the value being split on if it's in a regex group: `/(\d+)/`.

```
str.split(/(\d+)/).each_slice(2).to_a  # => [["a", "5"], ["bc", "2"], ["cdf", "3"]]
```

The resulting array can be broken into the string to be repeated and its associated count using `each_slice(2)`.

```
str.split(/(\d+)/).each_slice(2).map { |s, c| s * c.to_i } # => ["aaaaa", "bcbc", "cdfcdfcdf"]
```

That array of arrays can then be processed in a `map` that uses String's `*` to repeat the characters.

And finally `join` concatenates all the resulting expanded strings back into a single string.